# find the largest number in a text file and write its line

Tags: python

I have a txt file which looks like this: (the first line is the information about the columns and I have 150+ lines)

```
E1,   E2,  E3,  E4,  E5,    E6,       E7,     E8
abc, cba, dfa, gds, 60371, 42.1234, -2.12,    hkfka
grs, fx,  hgf, eff, 30331, 124,     31313.23,  gj
.
.
.
```

Expected output:

```
abc, cba, dfa, gds, 60371, 42.1234, -2.12, hkfka
```

I read this file with `with open` method, then I want to find the largest number in the E5's column. It's '60371' in this example. After I found it, I'd like to write it's whole line to a text file. I can find the largest number by adding the string to a list, but can't write it's line with this method.

```
    list = []
    with open(file.csv, "r") as m:
        text = m.readlines()[1:]
        text = [line.replace(' ', '') for line in text]
        for line in text:
            currentline = line.split(",")
            number= currentline[4]
            list.append(number)
            largest = max(list)
```

Edit: I'm not allowed to use any imports, such as panda, etc.

Comment: Hint: keep track of the largest number _and_ the line it appears in

Comment: Read about enumerate (https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/enumerate.html)

Comment: I you have more lines and columns (and the format of your file is clearly defined), you may want to use pandas for this. It would allow you to find the max value along a column without iterating through all lines.

Comment: another tip though not answering your question: you could use python's csv module, and you can refer to columns using symbolic names instead of positional indices

Comment: I'm not allowed to use any imports

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### 1. Without libs

```
with open('data.csv', 'r') as f:
    next(f)
    lines = [line.replace(' ', '').split(',') for line in f.readlines()]
    numbers = [int(line[4]) for line in lines]
    index = numbers.index(max(numbers))

with open('result.csv', 'w') as f:
    f.write(f'{index} ({lines[index][1]})')
```

Output:

```
0 (cba)
```

### 2. With `pandas`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
row = df[df['  E5'] == df['  E5'].max()]
row.to_csv('result.csv')
```

Output file:

```
,E1,   E2,  E3,  E4,  E5,    E6,       E7,     E8
0,abc, cba, dfa, gds,60371,42.1234,-2.12,    hkfka
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that I'm not allowed to use any imports.

Comment: Thank you, this one is the clearest and easiest solution that works fine.

Comment: I'd have a last question, if I'm allowed to. How can I write only the E1 and E3 part from the right line, instead of the whole line? So, the expected output would be ```0 (cba)```

Answer (score 0):

You can also store the text of the line that contains the largest number as an object, in a similar way to how you store the numbers themselves. Unless you need to extract *all* the lines and *all* the numbers, I would store only the latest largest number and its corresponding line text. For example:

```py
max_number = 0
max_line = ''
with open(file.csv, "r") as m:
    text = m.readlines()[1:]
    text = [line.replace(' ', '') for line in text]
    for line in text:
        currentline = line.split(",")
        number = int(currentline[4])
        if number > max_number: 
             max_number = number 
             max_line = line
```

This way `max_number` will be the largest number found in these loops, and `max_line` will be its corresponding line, but no other data from the file will be stored.

Comment: I can't use '>' between instances of 'str' and 'None'

Comment: you're right, I made an edit. You can initialize the `max_number` to 0 (if you know the numbers will be always equal or larger than 0), or something very small like `1e-30` otherwise.

Comment: it throws the same problem, but with 'str' and 'int'

Comment: Ok, looks like you might need to cast the number into an integer or float type (e.g. `number = int(currentline[4])`) as it's currently reading it as as a string.

Comment: Initialize `max_number` to `-float('inf')` as it is always less than any value, and do `float(currentline[4])`

Answer (score 0):

You can store the line on the loop.

```
list = []
cur_n = 0
max_n = 0
max_line = 0
i = 0
with open("file.csv", "r") as m:
    text = m.readlines()[1:]
    text = [line.replace(' ', '') for line in text]
    for i in range(0, len(text)):
        currentline = text[i].split(",")
        cur_n = int(currentline[4])
        if cur_n > max_n :
            max_n = cur_n
            max_line = i
print(max_n)
print(text[max_line])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple version, taking benefit of builtin CSV module. This is mainly useful if CSV format changes by fields being inserted, moved,
deleted etc. So we always use column id "E5":

```py
import csv

with open("test.txt", "r") as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, skipinitialspace=True)
    cur_max = -float("inf")

    for row in reader:
        val = float(row["E5"])
        if val > cur_max:
            cur_max = val
            max_line = ", ".join(row.values())

print(max_line)  # abc, cba, dfa, gds, 60371, 42.1234, -2.12, hkfka
```

It's also single pass, which might not be at all necessary.

I undestood first that by any imports you meant *external* imports, but any import is forbidden, then other answers could be used. Note that you want to cast values with `float` though, as input file seems to contain them, and `int` naturally discards any floating point values. If E5 is always int, then of course `int` is ok